# _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.usersCollection.doc(...).collectionGroup is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem like in the title. When I want to download my 'hives' using collectionGroup, this error pops up and I don't know what I can do to make it work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btxUU.png)

And my code:

```
async getHives() {
            await fb.usersCollection
                .doc(fb.auth.currentUser.uid)
                .collectionGroup('hives')
                .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                    let hivesArray = [];

                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        let hive = doc.data();
                        hive.id = doc.id;

                        hivesArray.push(hive);
                    });

                    store.commit('setHives', hivesArray);
                });
        },
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't post images of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 1):

A collection group query can't be contained within a specific document - there is no API for that.  It can only be performed across the entire database:

```
firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("hives")
```

If you want to filter all those documents to only receive certain ones, you can do that just like any other query.

```
firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("hives")
    .where("someField", "==", true)
```